# Why is the exterior algebra symbol a Lambda?

Tags: ho.history-overview

My guess is that this is because the capital lambda looks like a wedge. In this case why is the symbol a wedge.

Does anyone have any sources for this?

Comment: It's not a $\Lambda$, it's a $\bigwedge$.

Comment: Probably this question belongs at https://hsm.stackexchange.com/